# Add a legend to geom_point overlaid on geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-point

So I create a boxplot of data and then add a set point over that data. I want my legend to capture what the data type of the geom_points represents. Thanks!

```
ggplot(data = NULL) +
 geom_boxplot(data = discuss_impact_by_county,
              aes(x=reorder(State,discuss, FUN = median),y=discuss),
              outlier.shape = NA) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) + 
 labs(x = "States") +
 geom_point(data = by_state, 
            aes(x = State, y = discuss_happen_difference), 
            col = "red", 
            size = 3,
            show.legend = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a legend you have to map on aesthetics. In your case map something on the `color` aes, i.e. move `col="red"` into `aes()` and use `scale_color_manual` to set the value and the legend label to be assgined to the color label `"red"`.

As you have only one "category" of points you can simply do `scale_color_manual(values = "red", label = "We are red points")` to set the color and label. In case that your have multiple points with different colors it's best to make use of a named vector to assign the colors and legend labels to the right "color label"s, i.e use `scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red"), label = c(red = "We are red points"))`.

Using some random example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
discuss_impact_by_county <- data.frame(
  State = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE),
  discuss = runif(100, 1, 5)
)

by_state <- discuss_impact_by_county %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  summarise(discuss_happen_difference = mean(discuss))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_boxplot(data = discuss_impact_by_county,
               aes(x=reorder(State,discuss, FUN = median),y=discuss),
               outlier.shape = NA) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) + 
  labs(x = "States") +
  geom_point(data = by_state, 
             aes(x = State, y = discuss_happen_difference, col = "red_points"), 
             size = 3,
             show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "red", label = "We are red points")
```

[image]